# Get attr value of first child

Tags: jquery

I have the follwing code for assigning onclick to a `<tr>` row:

```
$("#tblDepartment tr").click(function() {
       alert($(this).eq(1).attr("field"));
   });
```

My HTML code is here:

```
    <tr class="trEven" id="trDepartment4">
            <td field="ID" style="display: none;" width="50px">4</td>
            <td field="DEPT_NM" width="100%">BID DEPARTMENT</td>
    </tr>
```

What I would like to do is tget first child's innerHTML. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to do something like this

```
$("#tblDepartment tr").click(function() {
   alert($(this).children('td').first().html());
});
```

This will show you the content your looking for :)

Answer (score 5):

```
$(this).children(":first").html();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$("#tblDepartment tr").click(function() {
   alert($(this).children('td').first().html());
});
```

Comment: How can we convert $(this).children('td').first().html() into an integer this need to be passed as parameter.

Comment: So you wish to parse the value of the `html()` as an integer? Try `parseInt( $(this).children('td').first().html() )`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function(){
    $(".trEven").click(function() {
        alert($(this).parent().find("td:first").html());
   });    
});
```

Working sample http://jsfiddle.net/H2gJV/7/

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#tblDepartment tr").click(function() {
   alert($(this).eq(1).attr("field#ID").html());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, here's a scoped solution.

```
$('#tblDepartment tr').click(function () {
  alert($('td[field=ID]', this).html());
});
```